# Find and Replace not working for batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, replace, find

Ok so I am creating a script with a built in updater, it creates a new file with the following code and updates several variables, but for some reason this isn't working anyone have any idea how to fix it or a similar script that will do roughly the same thing.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p "findthis"="1"
set /p "replacewith"="1.2.3"
call:updater
set /p "findthis"="2"
set /p "replacewith"="2.3.4"
call:updater
set /p "findthis"="3"
set /p "replacewith"="3.4.5"
call:updater
goto:eof

:updater
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (updateme.bat) do (

   set write=%%a
   if %%a==%findthis% set write=%replacewith%

   echo !write! 
   echo !write! >>%~n1.replaced%~x1
)
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several errors in this BAT.

Some are obvious syntax errors.

1. Read `help set` and correct all the `set /p "this"="value"` (hint: don't use /p option and correct the usage of " in the variable name)
2. you try to use %1 in a CALLed label. This is a passed parameter, and you are not passing it in your CALL. Read `HELP CALL`.

Some are logic errors.

1. The :updater code appends the updated string to the output file. It does so three times, so the final code is three times the original code with the strings changed.
2. Also, the code does try to find the string as a full line, a line containing just "1" in a BAT file does not make too much sense to me. You would probably want to find any text occurrence of "1".
3. Also, when you fix the previous problems, and if I understand correctly the intention of the code, you will eventually replace all "1" to "1.2.3" and then you replace all "2" to "2.3.4", so the original "1" will get replaced by "1.2.3.4.3".. and later on again, so it will finally be "1.2.3.4.5.4.3.4.5". Be careful with that.